# Kotlin, Dagger and Realm - DI concept problem

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, dagger-2

I'm starting this brand new project only for fun, but at the first steps I got a problem, there it goes:

I have this class "Note", it's a realm class as you can see below

```
@RealmClass
open class Note
    @Inject constructor (@PrimaryKey var id: String,
                var text: String,
                var badge: NoteBadge?
            ) : RealmObject() {

    fun getRandomNoteText(): String = "supposed to be random"
}
```

Then I have my Main activity class, where I already got Dagger working.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var note: Note

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        DaggerNoteComponent.create().inject(this)

        Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY", note.getRandomNoteText())
        Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY", note.badge?.getRandomBadgeText())

    }
}
```

It got tricky in terms of concepts, the code above doesn't compile, I have to add this line to my Note class to make it work:

```
    constructor(): this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "", NoteBadge()){}
```

However there I have `NoteBadge()` I'm creating an instance of NoteBadge manually, that's bad, I would like dagger did that.

I've tried sending a `null` value as parameter, but them I have a null NoteBadge at my MainActivity.

So do you have any idea how to fix that and make my dependency injection fully funcional? With no manual instance initializations?

**EDIT** -> Paste NoteComponent

```
@Component(modules = [NoteBadgeModule::class])
interface NoteComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Comment: Does `NoteComponent` has a module that provides a `@PrimaryKey String`, an unqualified `String` for text, and a `NoteBadge`?

Comment: @peterwhy I've pasted NoteComponent right now

Comment: You should not provide a RealmObject instance from Dagger, because Realm also creates instances of it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce could you answer this question, with the proper approach about realm?

Comment: Yes. Create the instance yourself, then in a transaction copy/insert to Realm, or use `realm.createObject()` inside a transaction to get an instance.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce there is any other way to work it out? I really would like to use realm and Dependency Injection in it's proper way. So I wouldn't like the idea of manually instance stuff.